# How can I make rows and columns of alternating image -> text, text -> image in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout on a website that will alternate Image -> Text, Text -> Image by row. I would like the image to take up 33% and the text take up 66%. I've tried several different methods with flexbox and grid but just can't get this. I feel as though it should be relatively simple and am probably over thinking it.

```
   _______
  |       |         Title A
  | IMAGE |     text text text
  |___A___|     text text text

                     _______
      Title B       |       |
  text text text    | IMAGE |
  text text text    |___B___|

   _______
  |       |         Title C
  | IMAGE |     text text text
  |___C___|     text text text
```

Is this best done with flex, grid, neither, or something else entirely?

Comment: Does it need to be dinamic or is it just static content?
Also, can you show what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution I can help with according to your input.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.row>div{
  padding:15px;
}
.text{
  width:66.6666%
}
.image{
  width:33.333%
}
.container .row:nth-child(2n+1){
  flex-direction:row-reverse
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>demo</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>

<style>
.box_sec {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box_sec2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .box {margin: 0 0 15px;}
    .box_sec {text-align: center;}
    .box_sec2 {flex-direction: column;}
}

</style>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box_sec">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="box"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="text_right">
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box_sec box_sec2">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="box"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="text_left">
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box_sec">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="box"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="text_right">
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: A brief explanation of your code will definitely help others. Make that a habit!